# AmCharts4 Remove Continent(s) in a MapChart

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I'm using `@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata/worldLow"` to create a simple map chart but don't need Antarctica. Would there be a way to hide or remove it but in such a way that the map utilizes  the space left by Antarctica to make the map adjust accordingly and make the other continents more prominent?

Initialization code:

```
import * as am4maps from "@amcharts/amcharts4/maps";
import am4geodata_worldLow from "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata/worldLow";
import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";

let chart = am4core.create("globediv", am4maps.MapChart);

try {
    chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;
} catch (e) {
  chart.raiseCriticalError(new Error("Map geodata could not be loaded."));
}

chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Projection;
chart.panBehavior = "move";

let polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
polygonSeries.data = myData;
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
```

[image: Would like to remove Antarctica from this view and have the rest of the map adjust accordingly]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `exclude` property in the polygonSeries as documented [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/#Including_and_excluding_objects)

```
polygonSeries.exclude = ["AQ"];
```

```js
let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);

try {
  chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;
} catch (e) {
  chart.raiseCriticalError(new Error("Map geodata could not be loaded."));
}

chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();
chart.panBehavior = "move";

let polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
polygonSeries.exclude = ["AQ"];
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/geodata/worldLow.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```